# How to I make a bot where if there are 4 roles tagged in a single message the bot bans them

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js V12, I am trying to make a bot where if someone tags 4 or more roles in the same message then the bot bans them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the following:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.roles.size >= 4) {
    message.member.ban({ reason: 'Spammed roles mentions' })
  }
})
```

Comment: When I inserted that code and test it I'm not even getting anything.  I put a console.log() in that command to see if I got any output. I got nothing. I'm  not sure whats going on.

Comment: command? where are you putting that code? in the main file or in a command file?

Comment: Nevermind its acually, 
```client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.roles.size>= 4) {
    message.member.ban({ reason: 'Spammed roles mentions' })
  }
})
```